# JavaScript array map, return numbers that are larger than 20

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried writing >=20 after the parseInt(string,10) but this does not work. So after I the array items have been converted to integer but do I check if they are greater than 20?

```
         const strings = ["10", "20","40","","50", "60", "70"];
         const numbers = strings.map(string => parseInt(string,10));
         console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: `.filter( el => el >= 20 ) `

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a condition and map the values for getting an array of numbers.

```js
var strings = ["10", "20","40","","50", "60", "70"],
    numbers = strings
        .filter(v => +v >= 20)
        .map(Number);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad, *larger* vs `>=`? anyway some condition is needed, either *greater* or *greater or equal*. the value gets converted by [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to number with the sign in front of `+v`. in case of a `NaN` value, the condition returns `false`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, i missed that.